# Array didn't modified after doing work with indicator

Tags: c++, indicator

I have some problems with indicator in c++. I've written program which call function - its task is add c-string "UWAGA: " before c-string included in array (which adress is sent as argument). If length of that c-string is greater than tab size, it should change the last three signs on '.' sign.
It works when I tried to print twsk pointer, but it isn't modifying tab[] content. BTW. inside my function when I printed w indicator it show only primary c-string. Could someone tell me why it doesn't modify my tab array?

PS. Sorry for my English.

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char * dopisywacz(char *w, int size);

int main()
{
 int size = 50;
 char  tab[size] = {"jakis c-string."};
 
 cout << dopisywacz(tab, size) << endl;
 
}

char * dopisywacz(char *w, int size)
{
 char *poczatek = w;
 char str[] = {"UWAGA: "};
 int dlugosc = strlen(w);
 char  temp[size];
 char *twsk = temp, *tpocz = twsk;
 
 int counter = 7;

 
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {
  *twsk++ = str[i];
 }

 while(*temp)
 {
  *twsk++ = *w++;
  counter++;
  
  if (counter == size)
  {
   *twsk -= 4;
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
    *twsk++ = '.'; 
   } 
   break;
  } 
 } 
 *twsk = 0;
 
 twsk = tpocz;
 while (*(w) = *(twsk))
 {
  w++;
  twsk++;
 }
 w = poczatek;

 return w;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason why you arent using `std::string` ?

Comment: Rama, could you tell more what you mean? Sorry, I'm beginner in C++ and I don't know how to use indicator well.

Comment: tobi303, I don't using namespace std:: because of make code easier. It's short program so there is no possibilities to argue with library names I think.

Comment: @maniekoo I was just joking and quoting laws in a science fiction novel. But regarding your code I think it makes abuse of pointers and nonsense names like temp. It is very difficult to understand and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to rollback the pointer before copying:

```
w = poczatek; // Restore pointer to initial position
while (*(w) = *(twsk))
{
    w++;
    twsk++;
}

return poczatek;
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex! Ideed I forgot about moving this pointer back there.

Answer (score 0):

Pass array as reference

```
char * dopisywacz(char*& w, int size);
```

Comment: Anderson, Thank you, it's also probably good thought, but this is excersice from book where was establishment to utilize pointer as argument. :)